# multiple IDs sharing 1 class CSS

Tags: html, css

I could do something like:

```
#id1 .class1, #id2 .class1{
   color:#FFF;
}
```

*But that seem's bulky, especially if I have a ton of ID's I want to share with 1 class.*

I'd much rather do something like:

```
#id1, #id2 .class1{
   color:#FFF;
}
```

*Obviously this doesn't work, but you get my drift.*

**Thoughts?**

### EDIT:

Probably should have mentioned I am over-riding CSS framework before I got flamed. Think bootstrap or zurb foundation. That's why there is a need to do this instead of just using a class. I was just wondering if there was any other inheritance selectors I wasn't aware of in native CSS.

Comment: Well you can't change the CSS syntax for what it is. Also questions should show what you've tried, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a language like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) which compiles to CSS. Just one of it's many features is that the following LESS:

```
#id1, #id2 {

  .class1 {
      color: #fff;
  }

}
```

Compiles to:

```
#id1 .class1,
#id2 .class1 {
  color: #fff;
}
```

That compilation can be done server-side ([lessphp](http://leafo.net/lessphp/) or less.js) or client-side (less.js) depending on your preference/needs.

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```
.class1
{
  color:#FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're overthinking it. The point of classes is to cover multiple items. all you need to say is:

```
    .class1{
       color:#FFF;
    }
```

this only won't work directly in 2 cases.

1. you have the class appearing elsewhere. Find (or create) a unique element surrounding your classes, such as

   ```
   ul .class1{
     color:#FFF;
   }
   ```
2. you have the class showing up on other types of elements. In this case:

   ```
   li.class1{
     color:#FFF;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest doing some reading about CSS specificity.

http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

First try writing a specific enough selector that will override the CSS framework.

This may involve doing something like

```
html body .class-i-want-to-override { /* ... */ }
```

It may require putting an `!important` on there, although that should be your last resort.

```
.my-class { color: pink !important; }
```

Finally I would suggest looking into a CSS preprocessor like [SASS](http://sasslang.org). This would allow you to write in a more efficient manner.

```
#special1,
#special2,
#special3 {
  .override {
    color: pink;
  }
}
```

Which would get compiled to:

```
#special1 .override, #special2 .override, #special3 .override {
  color: pink;
}
```

Comment: Somebody beat me to the preprocessor answer, but obviously less is an option too.

Comment: Thanks, I was just wondering if there was any other inheritance selectors I wasn't aware of in native CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a class?

Or apply, in the elements with these ID's, a common class? As a element can have a ID and classes at the same time..

In the code below is a basic example:

```
#commonClass .class1{
   color:#FFF;
}
```

Comment: I am overiding CSS framework. Think bootstrap or zurb foundation.

Comment: @DanKanze You should to try to rename the class, or apply a other name to the override and put the name of the class **AFTER** the class of the Boostrap/Zurb. This works too. :)